# Setting up release pipeline of kubernetes+istio with terraform+helm gives forbidden error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, azure-aks

I have tried now so many times setting up this pipeline in Azure devops where I want to deploy a AKS cluster and place istio on top.

Deploying the AKS using Terraform works great.

After this I try to install istio using helm but the command I use gives forbidden error.

```
helm.exe install --namespace istio-system --name istio-init --wait C:\Istio\install\kubernetes\helm\istio
```

I used the local path since this was the only good way I could find for helm to find the istio chart i have on the build agent.

The error message

```
Error: release istio-init failed: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "istio-galley-istio-system" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [{[*] [admissionregistration.k8s.io] [validatingwebhookconfigurations] [] []} {[get] [config.istio.io] [*] [] []} {[list] [config.istio.io] [*] [] []} {[watch] [config.istio.io] [*] [] []} {[get] [*] [deployments] [istio-galley] []} {[get] [*] [endpoints] [istio-galley] []}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tillerserviceaccount 56632fa4-55e7-11e9-a4a1-9af49f3bf03a [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:kube-system system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[] ruleResolutionErrors=[[clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:discovery" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:discovery" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:discovery" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found]]
```

The serviceaccount I use (system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tillerserviceaccount as you can see in error message) are configured using this rbac config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tillerserviceaccount
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tillerbinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: ""
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tillerserviceaccount
    namespace: kube-system
```

Still the error message says in the ruleResolutionErrors that it looks for cluster-admin but it is not found.

I even tried the extreme and set all service accounts as cluster admins to test:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-admins --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts
```

But even after that I get the same error with the same ruleResolutionErrors.

I am stuck and appriciate any help in what I can do differently.

Comment: pretty sure you need to run istio init first, not just run istio and call it istio init

Comment: I am pretty new to this.. When I downloaded the install pack for istio I got istio charts and istio-remote charts. no init. or you mean any other type of init. I am running like helm init to set up service account and such.

Comment: Reading up on github dokumentation the istio charts says: "The istio-init chart must be run to completion prior to install the istio chart." So ill download the init chart from there and run it first.

Comment: yeah, its in the same folder as istio, but called istio-init: `C:\Istio\install\kubernetes\helm\istio-init` - should be here. you should be using 1.1+

Comment: Tried the istio-init now but got the forbidder error still. "clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "istio-init-istio-system" is forbidden..." I can update the question with full error if needed.

Comment: i suppose you need to install helm with something like this: `helm init --service-account tillerserviceaccount --wait --force-upgrade --tiller-connection-timeout 600`

Comment: Currently i run: `helm init --service-account tillerserviceaccount --wait --upgrade`  ... I can try force-upgrade and connection timeout.

Comment: No changes, same error. Is there a command I can run before to check the current roles for the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the role binding we are using in dev clusters:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tillerbinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tillerserviceaccount
    namespace: kube-system
```

edit: in this case the error was due to AKS created without RBAC.

Comment: But as I have in my question I have the same just name my binding tillerbinding and another name of my service account no? (I tried with that apiGroup as well... But I guess that was before the init running.

Comment: I tried with setting apigroup as your example as well.. none of htem work..

Comment: ok, i suppose your cluster doesnt have rbac enabled. show your TF config you use to create aks

Comment: I was pretty sure I had.. But... hmm.. if I don't im som embaressed... Ill go double check..

Comment: wow... after all this time I had not double checked that it was enabled... it was not.. *smacks head*.. Add to your answer that I should double check that I have rbac enabled and I accept it.